# Shortcircuit Prefix Boolean Expressions

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, short-circuiting, postfix-notation

I have a bunch of boolean expressions written in prefix notation (also called [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)). Nested expressions in this format are very easy to evaluate (see the algorithm in the Wikipedia article).

The algorithm given on the Wikipedia page, however, does not do short-circuiting (when it evaluates `and f() g()`, it does not skip the evaluation of `g()` if `f()` is false). Is there any way to modify the algorithm to include short-circuiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same algorithm to build an expression tree: instead of evaluating `operand1 operator operand2`, create a node with `operand1` and `operand2` as children, and `operator` as parent.

Once you have the tree, you can evaluate it (top to bottom). You can short-circuit the evaluation by not evaluating one of the children (for example if the left child evaluates to `False` and the operator is `and`).

You'll notice that the given algorithm is equivalent to evaluation from bottom to top. While this is simple (and saves memory), you cannot apply short-circuiting because you never know if the branch you're in should even be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

I recently needed to do this and came up with an algorithm that seems to work:

1. Parse the expression using shunting yard, producing a postfix term series.
2. Find the parent operator of each term and store the offset.

   ```
   for term in terms:
       count = 0
       for next in remaining terms:
           if next type is function:
               count = count - (argument count - 1)
           else if next type is operator:
               count = count - 1
           else:
               count = count + 1
           if count is 0:
               next is term's parent
               offset = next - term
   ```
3. Evaluate the usual way and check for short-circuit after each operation. Jump ahead to term after parent term if applicable.

   ```
   for term in terms:
       if term is operator:
           pop 2 values
           evaluate (in reverse order)
           push result value
           if short-circuit (result is 0 and parent is AND, or result is non-zero and parent is OR):
               term = term + offset
       else if term is function:
           pop arguments
           evaluate (in reverse order)
           push result value
       else:
           push term value
   ```